# Error Eclipse Kura Installation with ecilpse committers

Tags: eclipse, kura

I've installed eclipse Kura with eclipse committers on windows 10 machine, I used eclipse installer. However, it showed the following error.

I will appreciate if you suggest me anything. Thanks for your help.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ45Y.png)
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'p2-repo-equinox_3.11.1' from location file:////C:/Users/Maury/iot-kura-develop/git/kura/kura/org.eclipse.kura.api/../target-definition/equinox_3.11.1/repository/: URI has an authority component -> 
...

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kura only supports OSX and Linux as official development environments. I would recommend running a Linux VM on your Windows host.

Comment: Recently I've installed eclipse Kura with eclipse installer on Linux/Centos machine. I set the  "Developer Type" to "User" and the "Eclipse Kura Git repository" to HTTPS (read/write). Now, I have some projects in my workspace, as follows:
Other Projects
Eclipse Kura
Target Platform
Examples
org.eclipse.kura.api show me 2 errors in pom.xml

I will appreciate if you suggest me anything. Thanks in advance